# & as separation and copy the data in array in migration script

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, migration

```
    const cArray = [
  {
    CompanyCd: 'Yello',
    CompanyName: "Yello & Productions",
  },
  {
    CompanyCd: 'Orange & proce',
    CompanyName: "Orange & proce c/o",
  },
  {
    CompanyCd: 'Lamus & FAMOUS',
    CompanyName: "Lemon",
  }
];
```

Also if I want to this condition only to "Yello & Productions" and "Lemon & Grass" only.

Like I am developing a script for data migration, and here is a scenario I am stuck.
So here  I have an array and what I've to do is in CompanyName if there's `&` in that, then I want to separate the company from that `&` for example Yello will be different and Production will be different but copying the same data of Yellow & production to both the newly separated ones. (data will be same) and then when once its created then, mark the Yello & production as isdelete= true.

Edited: I also want to perform the same thing on CompanyCd too.
suppose if CompanyCd is Single "Yellow" like no `&` then keep same code in both the newly created CompanyName

Answer (score 0):

The below is the code :

```
var cArray = [
    {
      _id: 36,
      CompanyId: 36,
      CompanyCd: "lle",
      CompanyName: "Yello & Productions",
      Competition: false,
      ParentCompany: 4,
      isdelete: false
    },
    {
      _id: 16,
      CompanyId: 16,
      CompanyCd: "Yello",
      CompanyName: "Orange & proce c/o",
      Competition: false,
      ParentCompany: 54,
      isdelete: false
    },
    {
      _id: 46,
      CompanyId: 46,
      CompanyCd: "Yello",
      CompanyName: "Lemon",
      Competition: false,
      ParentCompany: 74,
      isdelete: false
    }
  ];
  var companyList = ["Yello & Productions"]
  var arr = [];
  cArray.map(function(element){
      var companyName  = element.CompanyName;
      if( companyList.includes(element.CompanyName) && element.CompanyName.indexOf("&") >=0){             
        var split = element.CompanyName.split("&");
        delete element['CompanyName'];
        for(let i=0;i<split.length;i++) {
            arr.push(Object.assign({}, element,{"CompanyName":split[i].trim(), "isdelete":false})); 
        }
        element.isdelete = true;
        element.CompanyName = companyName;
        arr.push(element)
      } 
      else {
        arr.push(element);           
      }
  })
console.log("aa", arr);
```

OUTPUT:

```
aa [ { _id: 36,
    CompanyId: 36,
    CompanyCd: 'lle',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 4,
    isdelete: false,
    CompanyName: 'Yello ' },
  { _id: 36,
    CompanyId: 36,
    CompanyCd: 'lle',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 4,
    isdelete: false,
    CompanyName: ' Productions' },
  { _id: 36,
    CompanyId: 36,
    CompanyCd: 'lle',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 4,
    isdelete: true,
    CompanyName: 'Yello & Productions' },
  { _id: 16,
    CompanyId: 16,
    CompanyCd: 'Yello',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 54,
    isdelete: false,
    CompanyName: 'Orange ' },
  { _id: 16,
    CompanyId: 16,
    CompanyCd: 'Yello',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 54,
    isdelete: false,
    CompanyName: ' proce c/o' },
  { _id: 16,
    CompanyId: 16,
    CompanyCd: 'Yello',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 54,
    isdelete: true,
    CompanyName: 'Orange & proce c/o' },
  { _id: 46,
    CompanyId: 46,
    CompanyCd: 'Yello',
    CompanyName: 'Lemon',
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 74,
    isdelete: false } ]
```

Comment: but I only want to separate this to out of those list "Yello & Productions" and "Lemon & Grass" only.

Comment: @XFW SO if the companyName doesn't have `&` in that means you don't want that object itself??

Comment: No, I want to pass a fixed list of company names, only those companies need to be separated from &.

Comment: @XFW But your question doesn't have that requirement??

Comment: Why you're using the map function for looping only?

Comment: It is, right after array. But its just that, there's a list of companies only which needs tobe verify is matches that list then do the sepration.

Comment: @Ele Actually we can use plain `for` loop, suddenly map came into my mind, so I just used it..

Comment: which one is more efficient ? I am using it for data migration

Comment: And how about removing the space? after split?

Comment: Don't use the map function for this, it's ugly!

Comment: @Ele is there any performance issue will be there or generally its not good to use map?? Just for knowledge I'm asking..

Comment: @XFW Its solved ur problem?? If yes accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others.

Comment: @Subburaj I just updated few things in question, I want to get & separate to both companyName and CompanyCd both.

Comment: The function `map` is for generating a new array with the same length as the source array with transformed elements.

Comment: @XFW Its not recommended to answer a couple of question in same post. you have to post the requirement correctly in one shot, if going on changing the question when it will end.Kindly post as a separate question.

Comment: @XFW Based on your edit comes couple of questions. 1. Whether name and cd will be same?? 2. Also you want to add new object for `cd` also?? so in your case it will then have `4 objects`??

Comment: Yes, Like it would be like same logic of sepration but along with CompanyName

Comment: suppose if CompanyCd is Single "Yellow" like no `&` then keep same code in both the newly created CompanyName

Comment: @XFW Its hard to decode your requirement. Post as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can iterate through all objects from array, if the name of the current object contains &, create a new object with the name after split and push to a new array.
I made the example with clones, maybe you want to use the array later at something else

```js
const cArray = [{
    _id: 36,
    CompanyId: 36,
    CompanyCd: "lle",
    CompanyName: "Yello & Productions",
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 4,
    isdelete: false
  },
  {
    _id: 16,
    CompanyId: 16,
    CompanyCd: "Yello",
    CompanyName: "Orange & proce c/o",
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 54,
    isdelete: false
  },
  {
    _id: 46,
    CompanyId: 46,
    CompanyCd: "Yello",
    CompanyName: "Lemon_single",
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 74,
    isdelete: false
  },
  {
    _id: 46,
    CompanyId: 46,
    CompanyCd: "Yello",
    CompanyName: "Lemon & Grass",
    Competition: false,
    ParentCompany: 74,
    isdelete: false
  }
];




function separateCompanies(originalArr) {
  var companiesArrayClone = originalArr.slice();
  let allCompaniesByCriteria = []

  companiesArrayClone.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
    let cName = arrayItem.CompanyName;


    if (cName.includes("&")) {
      arrayItem.isdelete = true;
      let companies = cName.split("&");
      for (let name of companies) {
        let oneCompany = createCompanyObj(arrayItem, name)
        allCompaniesByCriteria.push(oneCompany)
      }
    } else {
      allCompaniesByCriteria.push(arrayItem)
    }
  });
  return allCompaniesByCriteria;
}

function createCompanyObj(company, name) {
  var singleCompany = jQuery.extend({}, company)
  singleCompany.CompanyName = name
  return singleCompany;
}

let companiesSeparated = separateCompanies(cArray);

console.log("arrayItems: " + JSON.stringify(companiesSeparated, null, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this statement *"Also if I want to this condition only to "Yello & Productions" and "Lemon & Grass" only."* from the OP

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for generating a new array that contains the objects already processed according to the above condition.

```js
const cArray = [  {    _id: 36,    CompanyId: 36,    CompanyCd: "lle",    CompanyName: "Yello & Productions",    Competition: false,    ParentCompany: 4,    isdelete: false  },  {    _id: 16,    CompanyId: 16,    CompanyCd: "Yello",    CompanyName: "Orange & proce c/o",    Competition: false,    ParentCompany: 54,    isdelete: false  },  {    _id: 46,    CompanyId: 46,    CompanyCd: "Yello",    CompanyName: "Lemon",    Competition: false,    ParentCompany: 74,    isdelete: false  },{    _id: 46,    CompanyId: 46,    CompanyCd: "Yello",    CompanyName: "Lemon & Grass",    Competition: false,    ParentCompany: 74,    isdelete: false  }],
      targets = [["Yello", "Productions"], ["Lemon", "Grass"]],
      result = cArray.reduce((a, c) => {
        let [left, right] = c.CompanyName.split("&")
        if (left  && right && targets.some(([l, r]) => l === left.trim() && r === right.trim())) {
          let newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
          newObj.CompanyName = left.trim();
          a.push(newObj);

          newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));
          newObj.CompanyName = right.trim();
          a.push(newObj)

        } else a.push(c);
        return a;
      }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @XFW is this scenario `{
    CompanyCd: 'Yello & Productions',
    CompanyName: "Lemon & Grass",
  }` possible?

Comment: @XFW you're modifying the question which is bad.

Comment: Sorry, just realized the req

Comment: Multiple scenarios might possible Like same logic of sepration but along with CompanyName

Comment: suppose if CompanyCd is Single "Yellow" like no `&` then keep same code in both the newly created CompanyName